# How to receive and filter array data coming from a report to a stored process is SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I've a **parameter** of named _ID who accepts **multiple values** from a list and send them to my **stored process**, lets say I've sent four values `(1,2,3,4)` in it, I'll receive them in my store process as,

```
_ID0 = 4
_ID1 = 1
_ID2 = 2
_ID3 = 3
_ID4 = 4
_ID_COUNT = 4
```

I'm receiving and filtering them as following.

```
%let ID = "&_ID";
%let Count  =  "&_ID_COUNT";

%macro IDs;
%global _ID0;

/* If more than one ID value was selected then cycle through the values */
    %if %eval(&_ID0 ge 2) %then %do;
          %do i=1 %to &_ID0;
            &&_ID&i
          %end;
    %end;

/* If only one ID value was selected  */
    %else &_ID
%mend;

****************************;

%macro filter;

%if &Count ne "0" %then %do;

 %stpbegin;
  proc sql noprint;
   create table users as 
   select *
   from work.users
   where id in(%IDs);
  run;
 %stpend;

%end;

%mend; %filter;
```

there is **not any error in log** above one is my code but It's not filtering anything. if user table has values 1-10 in id column user should be update with only 1,2,3,4

```
user
 id
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
  10
```

after filter i want

```
user
 id
  1
  2
  3
  4
```

I don't know What's wrong and did I miss any better approach.

Comment: Are you sure the ID variable is numeric?

Comment: In my report it's character / string

Comment: there is no error in my log file but I can't see any filter data either in webout file

Comment: You should get an error if you try to use `IN` operator with values that do not match the type of variable you are comparing it to.  Turn on MPRINT option to see the generated code in the log.  What is the purpose of the quotes that you are putting into `&count` and to the `%if` in the second macro?

Comment: If user didn't select any values then that portion wont run. I just don't know how to update dataset with an array data.

Comment: I don't understand why the above compiles the macro, without the `;` after `%else`... but it does, oddly enough, when I run it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work.  The %IDS macro could be more concise and might need more logic to deal with the inconsistency of how macro variables are created when count is less than 2.  So this macro will make sure that the 0 and 1 variables are populated (at least while the macro is running) before trying to loop over them.

```
%macro IDs;
%local i ;
%let _id0 = &_id_count ;
%if &_id0 = 1 %then %let _id1 = &_id ;
%if &_id0 = 0 %then -99999 ;
%do i=1 %to &_id0;
 &&_ID&i
%end;
%mend IDs;
```

Based on your example data it should work like this:

```
1071  %put (%ids);
(1  2  3  4)
```

What value do you want to emit if they don't select any values?  I have set this example up to generate -9999, but your other macro should already be skipping the call in that case so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: if user didn't select any value then filter won't execute

Comment: Yes your code is absolutely gonna work but what if user send data as 10, 5,8,2,3 etc?

Comment: `%filter` will run, but if `&_id0=0` then you will set `COUNT` to `"0"` and so it will not call `PROC SQL` or `%IDS`.  But since you have created the macro %IDS as an independent utility macro what do you want it to generate when `&id0=0` if it is called?

Comment: I thought you were using prompt to let user select from actual values in the data.  How could they put multiple values into the same macro variable?  If the user selected value 10,5,8,2 and 3 then _ID0 would be 5 and %IDS would generate `10 5 8 2 3`.  Note that SAS does NOT need commas in the list of values in the IN () operator.

Comment: yup I've already created a data set. if user select any values then filter will run and update data set according to the values else it'll print all the values of data set to webout. in sas management console -- > folders i created a stored process who receive multiple values and his name is _ID. it sends multiple values as _ID1, _ID2 etc and i want to update my dataset according  to those values